# Ruby on Rails - updating multiple models from the one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get my head around saving to multiple models from the one controller and it's probably really simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a User Model that has many `loanitems` and the `loanitems` belong to the user associations set up.

In my `loanitems` controller I want each `loanitem` create action to update a the `user.points`

So at the moment I have the following code that doesn't throw any errors but doesn't update the user model either.

```
def create
    @loanitem = current_user.loanitems.build(params[:loanitem])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @loanitem.save
        @loanitem.user.points = @loanitem.user.points + 50
        @loanitem.user.save
        format.html {redirect_to root_path, :flash => {:success => "Loan Item created" } }
        format.xml{render xml: root_path}
      else
        format.html {render 'pages/home' }
        format.xml {render xml: 'pages/home'}
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm also trying the following variation on a theme

```
  def create
    @loanitem = current_user.loanitems.build(params[:loanitem])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @loanitem.save
        current_user.points = current_user.points + 50
        current_user.save
        format.html {redirect_to root_path, :flash => {:success => "Loan Item created" } }
        format.xml{render xml: root_path}
      else
        format.html {render 'pages/home' }
        format.xml {render xml: 'pages/home'}
      end
    end
  end
```

But should I be sending some message instead to the `userupdate` controller instead?  That currently looks like this ...

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Profile has been updated!"}
  else
    @title = "Edit Profile"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Or I have heard that the business logic really should all be contained in the model so maybe the method should be written in `User.rb` and then called by the `Loanitems` controllers create method?

I know it's a real rookie question but any advice would be really welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a Transaction, so you can modify multiple items as a single atomic unit:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
      User.transaction do
        begin
          @loanitem = current_user.loanitems.create!(params[:loanitem]) # raises exception if it can't create
          @loanitem.user.update_attributes!(:points => @loanitem.user.points + 50) # raises exception if it can't update

          format.html {redirect_to root_path, :flash => {:success => "Loan Item created" } }
          format.xml{render xml: root_path}

        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
          format.html {render 'pages/home' }
          format.xml {render xml: 'pages/home'}

          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This allows you to have a simple happy-path where multiple objects are updated/created and roll-back all changes so far if anything goes wrong and render your error handling logic.  The objects will have the validation messages you can display to the user.

Comment: I haven't come across this Transaction before -  It looks good though - will give it a whirl and come back to you.  Cheers for the help!

Comment: Hey Winfield - gave this a shot - but it's failing on the  @loanitem.user.update_attributes!(:points => @loanitem.user.points + 50) line.  I tried making points attr_accessor in the User model but that throws You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+  (I was really only guessing there)

Comment: Winfield I got it to work - thanks to your help - I made one slight change as I have validations for email and password on User model - I needed to pass these values to with the update_attributes method - Thanks again for helping me out.